# Find an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

"Let a and b be two generators of a finite cyclic group G. Show that there exists an automorphism of G that maps a to b"

Im thinking that I need to find a $\phi: G \rightarrow G$, if its possible to show that this $\phi$ is an isomorphism, then I have showed that there exists an automorphism. But how should I think to find such a $\phi$?

Maybe I should note that I know that G is abelian.

Comment: Find instead two surjective homomorphisms $ℤ → G$ and use the first isomorphism theorem.  Alternatively, directly find two different isomorphisms $ℤ/nℤ → G$ which send $1$ to …?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $G$ is cyclic and generated by $x$ (and we write the group law as addition) then every element of $G$ can be written in the form $nx$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Similarly if $y$ is some other generator then every element of the group can be written in the form $ny$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: $\phi(a) =b^j$ ?

Comment: You need to explain what $a$, $b$, and $j$ are, otherwise that's just a random string of letters.

Comment: $b$ is one of the generators of the group. Since every element in the group can be generated from $b$ we have that $b^n = a$ for some integer $n$. $a$ -> $b^n$, or maybe more precise $\phi(a^j) = b^{jn}$ for some integer $j$

Comment: If $b^n = a$ then the map $\phi(a^j) = b^{jn}$ is the identity map and it doesn't map $a$ to $b$.

Comment: $\phi(a) = b$ Since b is also a generator. So we get back "whole" G from b.

Comment: Why does $\phi(a) = b$?  You said $a = b^n$ and $\phi(a^j) = b^{jn}$.  Plug in $j = 1$ and we get $\phi(a) = \phi(a^1) = b^{1n} = b^n = a$.

Comment: Thats the only map that maps a to b

Comment: That doesn't respond to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

As $a$ is a generator, $b = a^n$ for some $n$. Define the map $b^i \mapsto b^{ni}$. This is a homomorphism(Prove).

Similarly define the inverse. Or show directly that the above map is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning, I'll observe the following. Let $a$ be a generator of a finite cyclic group $G$. Now let $\phi$ be an endomorphism of $G$. Using the fact that $a$ generates $G$, we can characterize the image of any $x = a^r \in G$ like so: $$\phi(x) = \phi(a^r) = \phi(a)^r$$
(you should check that we don't get something different if we represent $x$ with a different power of $a$)

Therefore each endomorphism is exactly determined by specifying $\phi(a)$.

In your context then, just let $\phi$ be the endomorphism determined by $\phi(a) = b$. By construction it maps $a$ to $b$, you just need to check that it's an automorphism.

Comment: What is telling you that it is okey to move r, i mean why is $\phi(a^r) = \phi(a)^r$. I recognize this, but cant remember the theorem or "rule".

Comment: $\phi(a) = b $ feels like a "natural choice" but I dont understand your full motivation to this. Im thinking like this: we know $b$ is also a generator. So by letting $a$ map to $b$ then we are sure that we can generat $G$ again. I cant come up with any other map that would accomplish this, with the information I have.

Comment: @Olba12 The assumption is that $\phi$ is an endomorphism, so $\phi(g_1g_2) = \phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)$ for all $g_1,g_2\in G$. Then, by an induction argument $\phi(g^k) = \phi(g)^k$ for all $g\in G, k\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: ohh, yeah ofc @GPerez.

Comment: @Olba12 It's the only choice! If you want to map $a$ to $b$, then the only option is, well... $\phi(a) = b$. The trick is that this determines an endomorphism like this: we want to know the image of every $x\in G$, so find an $r\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x = a^r$ (this can be done because $a$ generates). Then define the image of $x$ as $\phi(a)^r = b^r$ (the same $r$). You need to check that this is the same element for any choice of $r$, and that in fact we have an automorphism.

Comment: As I understand u, i need to check that the equality $\phi(a^q)=b^q$ holds for all $q \in Z$.

Comment: @Olba12 That's not quite it. I mean that there are infinite $r\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=a^r$. If $r,s$ are two such numbers (i.e $x = a^r = a^s$), prove that $b^r = b^s$. In fact, this is true for any $g\in G$. If you take $r,s$ from before, then you can prove $g^r = g^s$. This is true because $r$ and $s$ have to be related in a special way.

Comment: If the order of $a$ is $n$ then $r$ and $s$ are congruent mod n

Comment: @Olba12 That is the crux of the matter.